# Define a parent template and extend it in ruby on rails 4 like it is done in twig with "extends"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twig, erb

In twig i can have a parent layout which defines some standard

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        {% block head %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
            <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - My Webpage</title>
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
        <div id="footer">
            {% block footer %}
                &copy; Copyright 2011 by <a href="http://domain.invalid/">you</a>.
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and then have a child layout which override some or all the blocks

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Index{% endblock %}
{% block head %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <style type="text/css">
        .important { color: #336699; }
    </style>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Index</h1>
    <p class="important">
        Welcome on my awesome homepage.
    </p>
{% endblock %}
```

how can i do something similar in Rails 4?I looked around a bit but didn't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a layout for each controller. `news.html.erb` for `NewsController` etc.

You can then use `content_for?`, `yield` and `render` to nest the controller specific layouts inside `application.erb.html`

Here's an example from official rails guides.

In `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= @page_title or "Page Title" %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "layout" %>
  <style><%= yield :stylesheets %></style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="top_menu">Top menu items here</div>
  <div id="menu">Menu items here</div>
  <div id="content"><%= content_for?(:content) ? yield(:content) : yield %></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In `app/views/layouts/news.html.erb`:

```
<% content_for :stylesheets do %>
  #top_menu {display: none}
  #right_menu {float: right; background-color: yellow; color: black}
<% end %>
<% content_for :content do %>
  <div id="right_menu">Right menu items here</div>
  <%= content_for?(:news_content) ? yield(:news_content) : yield %>
<% end %>
<%= render template: "layouts/application" %>
```

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts

Comment: This is horrible but i see no other way

Comment: Ok this is a little better but anyway thanks http://blog.55minutes.com/2014/02/easier-nested-layouts-in-rails-34/